# Laravel Lumen .env sometimes doesn't work

Tags: laravel, lumen

I'm working on a new project with Lumen and just noticed that the .env configuration sometimes doesn't work. It then uses the default locale and database settings, instead of mine.

I already tried to clear the cache and set the environment to production, but none of these have solved my problem.

```
APP_NAME=Lumen
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOCALE=de
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
```

Instead of applying the locale and database configuration, it sometimes just uses the default configuration, as if the .env wasn't there.

An example of the error that sometimes occurs:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986626/pdoexception-1044-sqlstatehy000-1044-access-denied-for-user-localhost

Comment: @RashedHasan I'm not missing the .env file, neither is the database configuration missing or incorrect (as it is working sometimes).

Comment: `sometimes doesn't work`- when? Doing what, exactly?  Is it reproducible?

Comment: It's just happening randomly when loading the page.

Comment: I faced same problem, then `php artisan config:cache` `php artisan config:clear` `php artisan cache:clear` worked for me. Would you please have a look to - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/env-not-reading-variables-sometimes

Comment: Lumen doesn't have these artisan commands. Only `php artisan cache:clear` seems to work, but did not solve my problem.

Comment: @Robin Did you manage to solve this problem? I´m in exactly the same situation with Lumen 7.x...

Comment: @Randolf Yes I did. It turned out that it was because of the Apache web server. With Nginx the problem did not occur anymore.