# Why PHP artisan migrate command showing error?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I try to run xampp on window 7. My php version is php 7.3.2. 
After run `composer install`, I run `php artisan migrate`.

My error is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'inventory' (SQL: select * from information
>     _schema.tables where table_schema = inventory and table_name = migrations)

and

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'inventory'

Comment: Did you confirm that you the user that is in your .env have permission in mysql ?

Comment: It seems that your database credentials are not correct/complete. The user is empty. Check the `.env` file and make sure there is a user name for connecting to database.

Comment: Check your .env file. If your configs are correct, check xampp running correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException (1044) SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1044\] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986626/pdoexception-1044-sqlstatehy000-1044-access-denied-for-user-localhost)

Comment: I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Specify your DB configuration as per below:
>   also make sure you have created a database.

```
DB_DATABASE= db_name
DB_USERNAME= user_name
DB_PASSWORD= password
```

Make sure your xampp is running.

Then after editing the `.env` file run below command.

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and then run,

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set `DB_USERNAME=` in the **.env** file, so you're getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to
>   database 'inventory'

Open the **.env** file and edit it. Just set up correct DB credentials:

```
DB_USERNAME=         //Your Database Username
```

`DB_USERNAME` should be set to `root` if you do not have a default username in the installation time

After changes of *.env* enter this command in your terminal for clear cache:`php artisan config:cache`

---

**NOTE: If you're still getting error**

Check your database configuration with tinker.

```
php artisan tinker
```

then write this will give you whole configuration check is it right or not.

```
>>config('database')
```